# Binding ModelForm to Model's instance when saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Suppose I have a model Article and its ModelForm ArticleForm.

```
>>> a_form = ArticleForm({"headline" : "My headline"})
>>> b = Article()
>>> b.save()
```

Now I would like to bind a_form to the b instance and save it (i.e. update b object with a_form fields). Is there a way to do that?

Something like:

```
>>> a_form.assign_instance(b) # WOULD LIKE TO HAVE SOMETHING LIKE THAT
>>> a_form.save()
```

Note: I know that I could just call

```
>>> a_form = ArticleForm({"headline" : "My headline"}, instance=b)
>>> a_form.save()
```

... but this is not the intention here. I need to know if I can sneak in the instance to the modelform right before I save it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for not just going with `instance=b`? Because as you say that's the way it's meant to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a_form.instance = b
a_form.save()
```

But the Django way to modify instance before form save is to override the forms `save()` method. You can do it like this:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self):
        instance = self.instance      # Do with instance what every you want
        super(ArticleForm, self).save()
```

Comment: Thanks! Could I do the same with inline formsets: a_formset.instance = b?

Comment: @GregoryR Yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it for inline formset? ArticleFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Reporter, Article, form=AticleForm, extra=extra_forms_article).
I added a question right after your answer, but it looks it was deleted

Comment: @GregoryR Sure, you can override inline formset's ``save`` method ([docs how to override inline formset's method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-methods-on-an-inlineformset)).